# how to set a value of a variable to IS NOT NULL in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a variable named @businessUnit which is a parameter to stored procedure. I m  using it in select statement with multiple conditions and some inner joins.

What I want is when parameter value of @businessUnit = 0 then I want to get all the records from the table

For e.g.,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[Resource ID] = r.Resource_ID,
[First Name]  = r.Resource_First_Name,
[Last Name]= r.Resource_Last_Name,
[Country] = c.Country_Name,
[Location] = l.Location_Short_Name,
[Function] = t.Trade_Name,
[Business Unit] = bu.BusinessUnit_Name,
[Product] = p.Product_Name,
[Assignment Start Date] = ra.Resource_Allocation_From_Date,
[Assignment End Date] = ra.Resource_Until_Date,
[% Training] = ra.Resource_Training,
[% Admin] = ra.Resource_Admin,
[% Roadmap] = ra.Resource_Roadmap,
[% Defect] = ra.Resource_Defect,
[% Commission] = ra.Resource_Commission

INTO #ResourceAllocated

FROM mResource r
INNER JOIN mResource ON r.IsDeleted = 0 
INNER JOIN mResourceAllocation ra ON  ra.BusinessUnit_ID = @businessUnit and ra.IsDeleted = 0 and r.Resource_ID = ra.Resource_ID and @Date >= ra.Resource_Allocation_From_Date and @Date <= ra.Resource_Until_Date
INNER JOIN mBusinessUnit bu ON bu.IsDeleted = 0 and bu.BusinessUnit_ID = @businessUnit
INNER JOIN mCountry c ON r.Resource_Country_ID = c.Country_ID 
INNER JOIN mLocation l ON r.Resource_Location_ID = l.Location_ID 
INNER JOIN mTrade t ON  r.Resource_Trade_ID = t.Trade_ID
INNER JOIN mProduct p ON ra.Product_ID = p.Product_ID   and p.IsDeleted = 0


GROUP BY bu.BusinessUnit_Name,
r.Resource_ID,
r.Resource_First_Name,
r.Resource_Last_Name,
c.Country_Name,
l.Location_Short_Name,
t.Trade_Name,
p.Product_Name,
ra.Resource_Allocation_From_Date,
ra.Resource_Until_Date,
ra.Resource_Training,
ra.Resource_Admin,
ra.Resource_Roadmap,
ra.Resource_Defect,
ra.Resource_Commission
```

Above query will give me a records which has specified @businessUnit

I want all records from it when user pass @businessUnit = 0
Thanks

Comment: Re-tagged with the `sql-server` based on the syntax used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `OR` condition should suffice:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
  WHERE (@Id = 0 AND Id IS NOT NULL) 
     OR (@Id > 0 AND Id = @Id)
```

So when `@Id = 0` only records where `Id IS NOT NULL` will be returned. When `@Id > 0` then only records with a corresponding Id value will be returned.

You mention Id is an IDENTITY column, therefore it won't ever have any NULL values. If you simply want to return all records when @Id = 0 then use:

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable
  WHERE (@Id = 0) 
     OR (@Id > 0 AND Id = @Id)
```

Based on your revised question I would suggest changing the JOIN on mBusinessUnit to:

```
INNER JOIN mResourceAllocation ra ON ((@businessUnit = 0 AND ra.BusinessUnit_ID IS NOT NULL) OR (@businessUnit > 0 AND ra.BusinessUnit_ID = @businessUnit)) 
and ra.IsDeleted = 0
and r.Resource_ID = ra.Resource_ID
and @Date >= ra.Resource_Allocation_From_Date
and @Date <= ra.Resource_Until_Date
```

As per comments you can specify the join criteria in the WHERE clause like this:

```
FROM mResource r
INNER JOIN mResource ON r.IsDeleted = 0 
INNER JOIN mResourceAllocation ra ON ra.IsDeleted = 0 and r.Resource_ID =   ra.Resource_ID and @Date >= ra.Resource_Allocation_From_Date and @Date <= ra.Resource_Until_Date
INNER JOIN mBusinessUnit bu ON bu.IsDeleted = 0 and bu.BusinessUnit_ID = @businessUnit
INNER JOIN mCountry c ON r.Resource_Country_ID = c.Country_ID 
INNER JOIN mLocation l ON r.Resource_Location_ID = l.Location_ID 
INNER JOIN mTrade t ON  r.Resource_Trade_ID = t.Trade_ID
INNER JOIN mProduct p ON ra.Product_ID = p.Product_ID   and p.IsDeleted = 0
WHERE (@businessUnit = 0 AND ra.BusinessUnit_ID IS NOT NULL) OR (@businessUnit > 0 AND ra.BusinessUnit_ID = @businessUnit)
```

Comment: but I have some other conditions with this so its giving syntax error near '='
should I update my question with other things ?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: I'd suggest to move all variables to WHERE clause away from joins.

Comment: @IvanStarostin how? Can you please explain.

Comment: @CSL's answer is correct and comprehensive, so you'd better wait for update from him and accept his answer. Examples of `WHERE` usage are present in his answer. The thing is about CTRL+X and CTRL+V.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE 
(Id = @id and @id<>0) 
   or  
(Id is not null and @id=0)
```